# name argument is required to req.get

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jwt

I have a nodejs server and a react frontend running on different instances. The frontend runs well without errors while the server returns this error after a successful login to my page

```
    TypeError: name argument is required to req.get
        at IncomingMessage.header (/home/tech/Desktop/REST/node_modules/express/lib/request.js:67:11)
        at module.exports (/home/tech/Desktop/REST/middleware/is-auth.js:5:28
```

I believe this part of my code is responsible for the error generation:

```
//extract token from frontend/client
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    const authHeader = req.get('');
    if (!authHeader) {
        const error = new Error('Not Authenticated');
        error.statusCode = 401;
        throw error;
    }
    const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1];
    let decodedToken;
    try {
        decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, 'secret'); //secret is used to validate token
    } catch (err) {
        err.statusCode = 500;
        throw err;
    }
```

Here is how I'm passing the token to the server

```
//pass token to the server
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/feed/posts?page=' + page, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.props.token
      }
    })
```

Comment: *name argument is required to req.get* - but you didn't pass anything in `req.get('');`.  Try `req.get("Authorization");`

Comment: Yes this fixed the issue, I thought the server would just pick the authorization header from the frontend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your middleware code should be updated, get the authorization header from request

```
//extract the token from the frontend/client
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
    if (!authHeader) {
        const error = new Error('Not Authenticated');
        error.statusCode = 401;
        throw error;
    }
    const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1];
    let decodedToken;
    try {
        decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, 'secret'); //secret is used to validate token
    } catch (err) {
        err.statusCode = 500;
        throw err;
    }
```